# Unable to add logo or header

Tags: media, headers, logo

I want to add a logo on my WordPress website by customizing the theme "Bard", but every time I select an image from my library, it leads to a **blank** page. The same happens with the header image. And yes, I've tried changing the theme but am facing the same issue.

**EDIT**: Yes, the size of the uploaded file matches the criteria, and yes, I can upload images in the library, and in posts and pages too. Also, I'm using Hostinger, not local host.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a plugin/theme conflict. First of all, I would recommend you to deactivate **all** your plugins, and then to install or activate default theme, like [TwentyNineteen](https://fr.wordpress.org/themes/twentynineteen/) or [TwentySeventeen](https://fr.wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/).

Do you still have your problem ? If you don't, we have found the solution (and then activate your plugin, one by one, to see the one who creates the issue, and at the end, reactivate your theme).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

- Have you had a look at the dev console while opening the media library? What does it say? Any errors?
- When you open your media library on the left menu can you upload anything?
- Have you checked your file size? Does it match the max upload size of your install?

Comment: Yes, the file size matches, and yes, I can upload images in the library and in posts and pages too.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the dev console (Btw, I'm not using local host). Could you guide me please?